# Calling a function/subroutine from a shared fortran (or maybe C) library from a Fortran program

Tags: c, fortran

## Background

I am trying to use the [Basic Model Interface (BMI)](https://csdms.colorado.edu/wiki/BMI) to initialize the [dflowfm model](https://oss.deltares.nl/web/delft3dfm) (that I have compiled from source to produce executables and shared libraries) from a fortran program.

I was able to do this successfully using a [python wrapper by openearth](https://github.com/openearth/bmi-python).

However, on my fortran program, this fails with a segmentation fault that doesn't tell me much.

After some digging around, I (think) I was able to locate the source code that points to the function/subroutine that I want to call to initialize the model.

Any help is highly appreciated!

## Issue

Below is my fortran program where I try to call the routine from the shared library as both a subroutine and function. Both fail with the error: `forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred` pointing the trace to the function/subroutine call. Here is the full trace:

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
libpthread-2.31.s  00007F04C9E19140  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libdflowfm.so.0.0  00007F04CB517080  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libdflowfm.so.0.0  00007F04CB517319  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
testbmifort        000000000040F2E1  MAIN__                     39  bmi_fort-test.f90
testbmifort        000000000040F25D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.31.so       00007F04C9C4CD0A  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
testbmifort        000000000040F17A  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Debugging trace:

```
39          call init(sharedDLLHandle, c_config_file, strln)
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f03c2181080 in GetDllProcedure () from /opt/dflowfm/lib/libdflowfm.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f03c2181080 in GetDllProcedure () from /opt/dflowfm/lib/libdflowfm.so.0
#1  0x00007f03c2181319 in bmi_initialize_ () from /opt/dflowfm/lib/libdflowfm.so.0
#2  0x000000000040f384 in test_df_bmi () at bmi_fort-test.f90:39
#3  0x000000000040f25d in main ()
#4  0x00007f03c08b6d0a in __libc_start_main (main=0x40f240 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fff9bf4d658, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff9bf4d648)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#5  0x000000000040f17a in _start ()
```

**bmi_fort-test.f90**
compiled as `ifort bmi_fort-test.f90 -L/opt/dflowfm/lib/ -ldflowfm -o testbmifort -traceback -warn interface -O0`

(in case you are wondering the shared library has been compiled with ifort too)

```
module bmi
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer(C_INT64_T), BIND(C, name="MAXSTRLEN") :: MAXSTRLEN
    ! interface
    !     integer(C_INT64_T) function init(config) result(iresult) bind(C, name='bmi_initialize_')
    !         use iso_c_binding
    !         character*(c_char) :: config
    !     end function
    ! end interface
    interface
        subroutine init(sharedDLLHandle, config, strln) bind(C, name='bmi_initialize_')
            use iso_c_binding
            type(c_ptr), value :: sharedDLLHandle
            ! integer(C_INT64_T), pointer :: dll_ptr
            character*(c_char) :: config
            integer(c_int) :: strln
        end subroutine
    end interface
end module bmi



program test_df_bmi
    use iso_c_binding
    use bmi    

    type(c_ptr) :: sharedDLLHandle
    ! integer(C_INT64_T), pointer :: dll_ptr
    character*(c_char) :: c_config_file
    character(*), parameter :: config_file = "/home/bmi-python/test_data/e02_f14_c040_westerscheldt/westerscheldt.mdu"
    integer(C_INT64_T) :: iresult
    integer(c_int) :: strln

    c_config_file = "/home/bmi-python/test_data/e02_f14_c040_westerscheldt/westerscheldt.mdu"
    strln = len(config_file)

    ! iresult = init(c_config_file)
    call init(sharedDLLHandle, c_config_file, strln)

end program test_df_bmi
```

The shortened output from the command `nm -D /opt/dflowfm/lib/libdflowfm.so` reveals the existence of the procedure I wish to call: `00000000015a5300 T bmi_initialize_`.
If I understand correctly from a few stackoverflow posts, the underscore at the end must mean it is a C routine.

Now, here are some scraps from the source files that I think resulted in the production of the routine I wish to call (the entire source tree is too huge to attach; I did an expression search in the source tree to filter out all the places that could be relevant and traced them back to these two snippets from two source files):

**sf1.f90** ([source](https://oss.deltares.nl/web/delft3dfm))

```
...
!> The initialize() function accepts a string argument that
!! gives the name (and path) of its "main input file", called
!! a configuration file. This function should perform all tasks
!! that are to take place before entering the model's time loop.
integer(c_int) function initialize(c_config_file) result(c_iresult) bind(C, name="initialize")
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: initialize
    
   use iso_c_binding, only: c_char

...

   character(kind=c_char),intent(in)    :: c_config_file(MAXSTRLEN)
   character(len=strlen(c_config_file)) :: config_file

   ! Extra local variables
   integer :: inerr  ! number of the initialisation error
   
...
    
   c_iresult = 0 ! TODO: is this return value BMI-compliant?
#ifdef HAVE_MPI

...

   ! Store the name
   config_file = char_array_to_string(c_config_file, strlen(c_config_file))

   ! Now we can initialize with the config_file


...


   ! TODO: check why these are needed to avoid a segfault
   KNX    = 8
   MXB    = 10
   MAXLAN = 500
   MAXPOL = MAXLAN

...

   CALL INIDAT()
   call api_loadmodel(config_file)

...

   c_iresult = flowinit()

   time_user = tstart_user

   ! Just terminate if we get an error....
   ! if (inerr > 0) stop
   ! initialize = 0
end function initialize
...
```

**sf2.c** ([source](https://oss.deltares.nl/web/delft3dfm))

```
...
long STDCALL BMI_INITIALIZE(int64_t * sharedDLLHandle,
    char   * config_file,
    int      config_file_len)
{
    typedef  (STDCALL * MyProc)(chvoid *ar *);
    MyProc proc = (MyProc)GetDllProcedure(sharedDLLHandle, "initialize");

    long error = -1;

    char * c_config_file = strFcpy(config_file, config_file_len);
    RemoveTrailingBlanks_dll(c_config_file);

    if (proc != NULL)
    {
        error = 0;
        (void *)(*proc)(c_config_file);
    }

    free(c_config_file); c_config_file = NULL;

    return error;
}
...
```

##### Side question:

Is there a way to check the necessary arguments and data types of the arguments of this routine from the shared library?

#### Additional info

This is the python program that was successfully able to initialize and run the model using the library:

**df_bmi-test.py**

```
import bmi.wrapper as bw

dflowfm = bw.BMIWrapper(engine='dflowfm', configfile='test_data/retracted/path.mdu')

dflowfm.initialize()
```

Here is the part of `bmi.wrapper` ([source](https://github.com/openearth/bmi-python)) I think is relevant to set this up:

```
...

def wrap(func):
    """Return wrapped function with type conversion and sanity checks.
    """
    @functools.wraps(func, assigned=('restype', 'argtypes'))
    def wrapped(*args):
        if len(args) != len(func.argtypes):
            logger.warn("{} {} not of same length",
                        args, func.argtypes)

        typed_args = []
        for (arg, argtype) in zip(args, func.argtypes):
            if argtype == c_char_p:
                # create a string buffer for strings
                typed_arg = create_string_buffer(arg)
            else:
                # for other types, use the type to do the conversion
                if hasattr(argtype, 'contents'):
                    # type is a pointer
                    typed_arg = argtype(argtype._type_(arg))
                else:
                    typed_arg = argtype(arg)
            typed_args.append(typed_arg)
        result = func(*typed_args)
        if hasattr(result, 'contents'):
            return result.contents
        else:
            return result
    return wrapped


...


def _load_library(self):
        """Return the fortran library, loaded with """
        path = self._library_path()
        logger.info("Loading library from path {}".format(path))
        library_dir = os.path.dirname(path)
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            import win32api
            olddir = os.getcwd()
            os.chdir(library_dir)
            win32api.SetDllDirectory('.')

        result = cdll.LoadLibrary(path)

        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            os.chdir(olddir)

        return result


    def initialize(self, configfile=None):
        """Initialize and load the Fortran library (and model, if applicable).

        The Fortran library is loaded and ctypes is used to annotate functions
        inside the library. The Fortran library's initialization is called.

        Normally a path to an ``*.ini`` model file is passed to the
        :meth:`__init__`. If so, that model is loaded. Note that
        :meth:`_load_model` changes the working directory to that of the model.

        """

        if configfile is not None:
            self.configfile = configfile
        try:
            self.configfile
        except AttributeError:
            raise ValueError("Specify configfile during construction or during initialize")
        abs_name = os.path.abspath(self.configfile)
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(self.configfile) or '.')
        logmsg = "Loading model {} in directory {}".format(
            self.configfile,
            os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
        )
        logger.info(logmsg)
        # Fortran init function.
        self.library.initialize.argtypes = [c_char_p]
        self.library.initialize.restype = None
        # initialize by abs_name because we already chdirred
        # if configfile is a relative path  we would have a problem
        ierr = wrap(self.library.initialize)(abs_name)
        if ierr:
            errormsg = "Loading model {config} failed with exit code {code}"
            raise RuntimeError(errormsg.format(config=self.configfile,
                                               code=ierr))
...
```

Comment: Compile for debugging with debugging flags enabled. `-traceback` on its own does not help much, you also need `-g` to get more than just addresses. And alse `-check` to check for many common types of bugs.

Comment: "*If I understand correctly from a few stackoverflow posts, the underscore at the end must mean it is a C routine.*" Quite the opposite. Underscores are automatically added to Fortran procedures. But a C subroutine can also be manually named that way.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава hanks for taking the time to look into the issue. I tried to add the flags as suggested and used gdb to debug it. But I am not able to make much out of it. It seems like the library is read: `#0  0x00007f03c2181080 in GetDllProcedure () from /opt/dflowfm/lib/libdflowfm.so.0`. And the routine is found: `#1  0x00007f03c2181319 in bmi_initialize_ () from /opt/dflowfm/lib/libdflowfm.so.0`.

Comment: And this is the last trace leading to the error: `#4  0x00007f03c08b6d0a in __libc_start_main (main=0x40f240 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fff9bf4d658, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff9bf4d648)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:308`

Comment: I am have a feeling that the error may be arising from the fact that my routine call is not matching the routine and arg types. Do you maybe know a way I can check the routine and argument types from the shared library?

Comment: In general such a check is not possible.